# Grpc python SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE

Tags: python, openssl, grpc, handshake

I'm working in a project which is based on Grpc. Nevertheless I have a problem when I try to connect to my service with the following code:

```py
import grpc
from grpc_health.v1 import health_pb2
from grpc_health.v1 import health_pb2_grpc

with open('ca_chain_pem_path', 'rb') as f:
    ca = f.read()
credentials = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(ca)
with grpc.secure_channel('host_domain:50051', credentials) as channel:
    stub = health_pb2_grpc.HealthStub(channel)
    request = health_pb2.HealthCheckRequest()
    response = stub.Check(request)
```

It raises the following error:
`Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE` and I do not know how to fix it. My service is located behind a load balancer in AWS and I can connect to it via grpcurl and grpcui but not with python and it's frustrating.

I was looking for a solution in google and in this page without success. Thanks in advance

PD: the certificate I'm reading in the code is the one that sign the deployed service in the aws domain

Comment: Did you get this working? I have a similar issue but no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the same result.
I've found that issue - [grpcioo failing on TLS with ED25519 algorithm](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/24252)

As it's proposed in issue, I have reinstalled *grcpio* with that environment variable

`export GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=1`

and ssl error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

if it's a private certificate I think you should also specify it to ssl_channel_credentials:

```
with open(certs_folder / "client.key", 'rb') as fh:
    key = fh.read()
with open(certs_folder / "client.pem", 'rb') as fh:
    cert = fh.read()
with open(certs_folder / "server.pem", 'rb') as fh:
    root_ca = fh.read()

credentials = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(root_certificates=root_ca, 
    private_key=key, certificate_chain=cert)
```

does the host_domain:50051 matches what's in the certificate? If not you may need to use `options=(('grpc.ssl_target_name_override',` in the grpc.secure_channel

Comment: but the client does not need to authenticate against server too, so what certs I need to stabilish the connection? The certificates also includes a wildcard so any host in our domain match the CN

Comment: Okay, then this could also be when the client and server could not agree on a cipher to use. Can you get some debug information on which cipher suites server and client announce?

Comment: Of course, I get the ciphers method from the server cert and put them into the client by setting the os env `os.environ["GRPC_SSL_CIPHER_SUITES"] = "HIGH+ECDSA"`. Nevertheless in my stack trace I found something like `TSI_PROTOCOL_FAILURE` and `tis_code=10`. Moreover the handshake stops after the `TLS client read_server_hello` step